# How to find most frequent levels of factors?

Tags: r

I still learning R and apologizing for lack of knowledge.

My data has 192 countries and looks similar to that:

```
    # Given some data which resemble the original data
    cars_produced <- data.frame(countries =  c("US", 
                                     "US",
                                     "US", 
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "US",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "France",
                                     "Norway",
                                     "Norway",
                                     "Norway",
                                     "Norway",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany",
                                     "Germany"
    ),
    manufacturer   =   c(  "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "BMW",
                           "General motors",
                           "General motors",
                           "General motors",
                           "General motors",
                           "General motors",
                           "Ford",
                           "Ford",
                           "Ford",
                           "Toyota",
                           "Toyota",
                           "Toyota",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "BMW",
                           "BMW",
                           "BMW",
                           "Toyota",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "BMW",
                           "BMW",
                           "BMW",
                           "BMW",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Volkswagen",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes",
                           "Mercedes"

    ),

    model=c("GLK",
             "M",
             "Passat",
             "Golf",
             "Caddy",
             "M4",
             "Hammer",
             "Pontiac",
             "Chevrolet",
             "Corvette",
             "Cadillac",
             "KA",
             "Fiesta",
             "Taurus",
             "Yaris",
             "Carina",
             "Briska",
             "GLK",
             "M",
             "GL",
             "C",
             "M4",
             "X5",
             "i8",
             "Carina",
             "Passat",
             "Golf",
             "Caddy",
             "Sharan",
             "Polo",
             "M4",
             "X5",
             "i8",
              "E9",
             "Passat",
             "Golf",
             "Caddy",
             "Sharan",
             "GLK",
             "M",
             "GL",
             "C")
    )




    > cars_produced
    countries   manufacturer     model
    #1         US       Mercedes       GLK
    #2         US       Mercedes         M
    #3         US     Volkswagen    Passat
    #4         US     Volkswagen      Golf
    #5         US     Volkswagen     Caddy
    #6         US            BMW        M4
    #7         US General motors    Hammer
    #8         US General motors   Pontiac
    #9         US General motors Chevrolet
    #10        US General motors  Corvette
    #11        US General motors  Cadillac
    #12        US           Ford        KA
    #13        US           Ford    Fiesta
    #14        US           Ford    Taurus
    #15        US         Toyota     Yaris
    #16    France         Toyota    Carina
    #17    France         Toyota    Briska
    #18    France       Mercedes       GLK
    #19    France       Mercedes         M
    #20    France       Mercedes        GL
    #21    France       Mercedes         C
    #22    France            BMW        M4
    #23    France            BMW        X5
    #24    Norway            BMW        i8
    #25    Norway         Toyota    Carina
    #26    Norway     Volkswagen    Passat
    #27    Norway     Volkswagen      Golf
    #28   Germany     Volkswagen     Caddy
    #29   Germany     Volkswagen    Sharan
    #30   Germany     Volkswagen      Polo
    #31   Germany            BMW        M4
    #32   Germany            BMW        X5
    #33   Germany            BMW        i8
    #34   Germany            BMW        E9
    #35   Germany     Volkswagen    Passat
    #36   Germany     Volkswagen      Golf
    #37   Germany     Volkswagen     Caddy
    #38   Germany     Volkswagen    Sharan
    #39   Germany       Mercedes       GLK
    #40   Germany       Mercedes         M
    #41   Germany       Mercedes        GL
    #42   Germany       Mercedes         C
```

My questions are:

1. How many car models are generally produced by countries (from which manufacturers)?

   2. How can I select the most and least popular car models worldwdide (with their corresponding manufacturers)?

In that regard I have tried to use the

```
    library(dplyr)
```

For question one I have tried the following:

```
    count_by_manufacturer<- cars_produced[,-1] %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

Most pupular. However I dont know hwo to get the correpsonding manufacturer:

```
    Countries_by_models<- cars_produced[,-2] %>% group_by(model) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Have a look at `?table`

Comment: State your questions *in your question*, not as comments in your code.

Comment: Add `%>% left_join(cars_produced[-1])` to the end of the second expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your desired results using `dplyr`.

For the first and second results, we don't need to deselect the column that is not being grouped. Instead, to find the `count` of models manufactured by `countries`, `group_by` the `countries` and `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
cars_produced %>% group_by(countries) %>% summarise(count=n())
### A tibble: 4 x 2
##  countries count
##     <fctr> <int>
##1    France     8
##2   Germany    15
##3    Norway     4
##4        US    15
```

To find the `count` of models by `manufacturer`, `group_by` the `manufacturer`:

```
cars_produced %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% summarise(count=n())
### A tibble: 6 x 2
##    manufacturer count
##          <fctr> <int>
##1            BMW     8
##2           Ford     3
##3 General motors     5
##4       Mercedes    10
##5         Toyota     4
##6     Volkswagen    12
```

To find the most popular `model` (and its `manufacturer`), first `group_by` the `model` and create a column containing the count by `model`. Then, `ungroup` and `filter` to keep only those rows with the `max(count)`. Finally, `group_by` both `manufacturer` and `model` and `summarise` the `count`:

```
cars_produced %>% group_by(model) %>% mutate(count=n()) %>% 
                  ungroup %>% filter(count==max(count)) %>% 
                  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% summarise(count=first(count))
##Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
##Groups: manufacturer [?]
##
##  manufacturer  model count
##        <fctr> <fctr> <int>
##1          BMW     M4     3
##2     Mercedes    GLK     3
##3     Mercedes      M     3
##4   Volkswagen  Caddy     3
##5   Volkswagen   Golf     3
##6   Volkswagen Passat     3
```

To find the least popular model, do the same except `filter` to keep only rows with the `min(count)`:

```
cars_produced %>% group_by(model) %>% mutate(count=n()) %>% 
                  ungroup %>% filter(count==min(count)) %>% 
                  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% summarise(count=first(count))
##Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
##Groups: manufacturer [?]
##
##     manufacturer     model count
##           <fctr>    <fctr> <int>
##1             BMW        E9     1
##2            Ford    Fiesta     1
##3            Ford        KA     1
##4            Ford    Taurus     1
##5  General motors  Cadillac     1
##6  General motors Chevrolet     1
##7  General motors  Corvette     1
##8  General motors    Hammer     1
##9  General motors   Pontiac     1
##10         Toyota    Briska     1
##11         Toyota     Yaris     1
##12     Volkswagen      Polo     1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might be helpful:

```
countries <- table(cars_produced$countries)
sort(countries, T)
Germany      US  France  Norway 
     15      15       8       4
```

And just to point it out:

```
country_manufac <- with(cars_produced, table(countries, manufacturer ))
country_manufac
         manufacturer
countries BMW Ford General motors Mercedes Toyota Volkswagen
  France    2    0              0        4      2          0
  Germany   4    0              0        4      0          7
  Norway    1    0              0        0      1          2
  US        1    3              5        2      1          3
```

And if this gets too verbose, try

```
apply(country_manufac, 1, which.max)
 France Germany  Norway      US 
      4       6       6       3
```

which for each country gives you the index of the most popular car brand. For instance, France likes car brand number 4, which is Mercedes. But please familiarize yourself with what happens when there are ties. A good starting point would be to look at `?which.min`. You may also want to have a look at `?ftable`.

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question:

```
ag <- aggregate(model~countries+manufacturer, df, length)
ag[order(ag$countries),] # just in case you want to see them sorted

   # countries   manufacturer model
# 1     France            BMW     2
# 7     France       Mercedes     4
# 10    France         Toyota     2
# 2    Germany            BMW     4
# 8    Germany       Mercedes     4
# 13   Germany     Volkswagen     7
# 3     Norway            BMW     1
# 11    Norway         Toyota     1
# 14    Norway     Volkswagen     2
# 4         US            BMW     1
# 5         US           Ford     3
# 6         US General motors     5
# 9         US       Mercedes     2
# 12        US         Toyota     1
# 15        US     Volkswagen     3
```

Or equivalently (as a cross-tabular):

```
table(df$countries, df$manufacturer)

         # BMW Ford General motors Mercedes Toyota Volkswagen
  # France    2    0              0        4      2          0
  # Germany   4    0              0        4      0          7
  # Norway    1    0              0        0      1          2
  # US        1    3              5        2      1          3
```

This gives you the number of models per country:

```
aggregate(model~countries, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

  # countries model
# 1    France     8
# 2   Germany    13
# 3    Norway     4
# 4        US    15
```

Your second question is not clear. What do you mean by most/least popular? How about any ties?